# Matar e responder JSON com PHP

Tags: php

Meu framework submete formulários com uma concatenação fixa informando o tipo do dado, qual validação ele deve passar, o nome de campo em relação a tabela no BD e o valor, seria algo como:

```
data[0][]company_razao_social::Empresa::company_name::text::undefined
```

Existe uma classe que explode a string e monta um array pra verificar:

```
  {
        $arr = [];
        $key = 0;
        //print_r($_POST);
        foreach ($POST['data'] as $row)
        {
            $data = $row[0];
            $EXP = explode('::', $data);
            $label = $EXP[0];
            $value = $EXP[1];
            $validation = $EXP[4];
            if ($label == 'password')
            {
                $arr[$key][$label] = sha1($value); 
            } else
            {
                $arr[$key][$label] = utf8_encode(\vidbModel\validate::get_rs($value,$validation));
            }
            $key += 1;
        }
        return $arr;
    }
```

Isso me devolve um array:

Se foi validado:

```
$data['company_razao_social'] = 'Valor do campo';
```

Ou, caso não tenha sido:

```
$data['company_razao_social'] = 'O campo não foi validado (Aqui vem a resposta de não ter sido)';
```

O problema disso é tratar no cliente qual é o erro quando há algúm.

O que eu quero é:

> Matar a função, e devolver um json só com o erro quando o dado não passar na validação, ao invés de continuar e devolver todo o formulário com todos os erros que houveram e ter que tratar tudo isso client side.

```
//Dentro do loop para desconcatenar
{
    $arr[$key][$label] = utf8_encode(\vidbModel\validate::get($value,$validation));
    if($$arr[$key][$label] = 'Possui erro'){
        die('devolver um json aqui');
    }
}
```

Dessa forma, a resposta não vem json, e não estou conseguindo devolver json com die, existe outra forma de matar o método e devolver ? .

Obs: break não funciona também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um pouco confuso, mas acredito que seria algo como:

```
//Dentro do loop para desconcatenar
{
    $arr[$key][$label] = utf8_encode(\vidbModel\validate::get($value,$validation));
    if($$arr[$key][$label] = 'Possui erro'){
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(["erro" => "Mensagem de erro"]);
        die();
    }
}
```

Assim, a função `header` envia o devido cabeçalho HTTP indicando que a resposta será um JSON, o `echo` define qual será o corpo da resposta HTTP, utilizando a função `json_encode` para simplificar, e, por fim, a função `die` mataria o processo, finalizando a execução.

Comment: É isso mesmo, deu certo, eu não havia testado responde e matar depois, estava tentando devolver junto com o die, ai não conseguia trazer em json, nem há necessidade do header, ja defino o header json no controller.

Comment: Acho que é ainda melhor utilizar `exit(0)` para matar o processo, pois assim é matado de forma bem sucedida, sem correr o risco do servidor enviar uma resposta 500 ao cliente. Aliás, talvez seja até interessante definir o status da resposta no código.

Comment: Eu simplifiquei o código ali, mas possui uma resposta informando true e false pra saber o status, é que possui uma série de verificações que não eram no contexto da pergunta, ai removi do exemplo pra ficar mais fácil, vou verificar com exit também, mas acho que os dois vão funcionar, só não sei a real diferença de um pro outro.